# Using CausalImpact in R, observed data affected by event that could not affect priors

Tags: r, causalimpact

I am just starting out using the Causal Impact package in R. I am looking at observed data where I know there will be periods of extra traffic due to outside forces. However I cant find any unbiased priors to feed this in. Is there a way to say, 'At this point during the timescale, we expect to see and uplift' to help the model map it more efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a gap between pre- and post-period by specifying the arguments such `pre.period[1]` does not immediately follow `pre.period[2]`. With this, it is possible to exclude some time period around the intervention that is known to be affected by external factors.

Apart from that, there is currently no possibility to exclude e.g. specific time points of some covariates.